# Simplify JavaScript code. document.getElementById

Tags: javascript

I have this code. The goal is to write the number when needed in a specific field. The problem is that the code is large. Can I simplify the code more?

HTML code

```
<div class="btn-group mr-2" role="group" aria-label="First group">
  <button type="button" onclick="e1()" class=" btn">01</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="e30()" class="btn">30</button>
</div>
```

JavaScript code

```
function e1() {
  document.getElementById("epis_n").value = "1";
  document.getElementById("order").value = "1";
}

function e30() {
  document.getElementById("epis_n").value = "30";
  document.getElementById("order").value = "30";
}
```

Comment: why the java tag?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What does "all headlines refuse" mean? Why do you consider 12 lines of code "large"?

Comment: Just create a single function that receives the desired value as a parameter `function setValue(value) { ... }`. then use it like this `onclick="setValue(30)"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a function that takes an argument instead.

HTML:

```
  <button type="button" onclick="e(1)" class="btn">01</button>
  ...
  <button type="button" onclick="e(30)" class="btn">30</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
function e(n) {
    document.getElementById("epis_n").value = n.toString();
    document.getElementById("order").value = n.toString();
}
```

Comment: Excellent..Thank you very much